# Query many species simultaneously from GBIF with **rgbif**

Tags: r, database, loops

I want to search for multiple species occurrences in gbif.org using the **rgbif** package.

To do a single search, I would use:

```
sq1 <- name_backbone("Acantholimon vedicum")$usageKey
occurences <- occ_count(taxonKey=sq1, georeferenced=TRUE)
```

How can I repeat this, searching an arbitrary number of taxa?

Comment: if you are running shell command you can create a bash file for loop running the command.  you can showtly learn how to do it from any tutorial site like https://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/shell_scripting.htm

Comment: Most of the **rgbif** functions can be applied to lists.... for example
`name_backbone_checklist(<your_species_list>...)`

Comment: I like to wrap repeating things in `map` family function from **purrr** or **furrr**, so if `sq1` were a list of names from your `name_backbone` search, something like `occ <- map(sq1, function(x) {occ_count(taxonKey = x, georeferenced = TRUE)})`

Comment: @MichaelRoswell that's the answer I was looking for, thanks